# How to select unique values in column and all null values from same column in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, unique, distinct

i'm trying to solve my problem and still cant make it. I have table "Products" which has column "product_bundle_id" (its nullable) and i want to select all of the products which have null in "product_bundle_id" and also all rows with unique value in this column.

Basically i need select all products which doesnt have Bundle and all products that have it but only one products with same bundle.

I'm trying something like this, but it selects only unique values including one unique null. Same result i can do it by distinct, but another trouble is that i need select multiple columns from that table, not only distinct by.

```
Product::where('product_status', 'active')
                                ->select(['product_bundle_id'])
                                ->groupBy('product_bundle_id')
                                ->get();
```

Thanks for ideas.

/// update

Just found the solution. In my case is enough change database strict mode to false. Then selecting multiple columns and group by one of them works. Here is my edited code. I use IFnull function and all null values set to unique id as alias. After that group by the alias.

```
DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('product_bundles', 'product_bundles.id', '=', 'products.product_bundle_id')
        ->select('products.*', DB::raw("IFNULL( products.product_bundle_id, CONCAT('id_',products.id)) as group_by"))
        ->groupBy('group_by')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can just fetch all Products into collection first `$p = Product::get();` and then apply appropriate collection method to $p ?

`$unique = $p->unique('product_bundle_id')` or `$allNull = $p->where('product_bundle_id', NULL);`

Can use chunk() to lower compute power.

Comment: Thanks, i just edited the question with solution what i found